# Utilização de Classe externa com erro (non-static method)

Tags: java, android

Criei uma *Class* externa chamada *Util* para deixar alguns métodos que eu sempre uso, mas está dando erro na hora de usar eles, segue código da *Util*:

```
package com.hs.gui.testelayout.util;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
/**
 * Created by Gui_j on 25/04/2016.
 */
public class Util extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void backAppBar(String telaTitulo){
     //getSupportActionBar() são métodos nativos do _Android_ que chamam um botão na tela
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setTitle(telaTitulo);
    }
}
```

se eu manter do jeito que está ai, tenho um erro de retorno:
[image: erros]

Para tirar o erro eu deveria tornar o

```
public void backAppBar(String telaTitulo){...}
```

em

```
public static void backAppBar(String telaTitulo){...}
```

Mas fazendo isso eu *ganho* outro erro:
[image: erros2]

Que para corrigir eu devo tirar o `static` adicionado, mas com isso voltamos ao problema inicial.
Sobre a [`getSupportActionBar()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar())

Comment: Onde está esse método "getSupportActionBar()"? se ele for da class Util, deve ser estático também.

Comment: Não seria melhor passar o context como argumento recuperar a actionbar dele ao invés de criar uma classe que estende actionbar?

Comment: @user5978 o método esta na biblioteca, eu importo ele aqui → `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

Comment: @DiegoF como assim?

Comment: O método não é estático. Você não pode acessar um método não estático, dentro de um método estática. A menos que você possua uma instância do objeto em questão. Você pode instanciar o objeto AppCom..., ou receber ele como parâmetro, em vez de estende-lo.

Comment: Instanciar Util, creio que seja a pior solução dentre as já sugeridas aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto ocorre pois o método `getSupportActionBar` não é estático, então ele não terá acesso em um método estático.

Existem duas formas para resolver esta situação:

**Classe abstrata**

Esta classe terá todos os métodos comuns as demais Telas.

Exemplo:

```
public abstract class ActivityModel extends AppCompatActivity{
    public void backAppBar(String telaTitulo){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(telaTitulo);
    }

}
```

Nas suas telas, ao invés de extender de `AppCompatActivity`, deverá extender de `ActivityModel`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityModel {
…
}
```

**Classe Utilitária**

Outra forma seria cria uma classe utilitária com os métodos comuns. A diferença é que ao invés de herdar, você deverá passar via parametros as informações da `Activity` (como sitado nos comentários acima pelo [DiegoF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595/diego-f)) :

```
public class Utils  {
    public static  void backAppBar(String telaTitulo, AppCompatActivity activity){
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(telaTitulo);
    }
```

}

Comment: +1 pois a segunda sugestão foi que dei nos comentários :)